# Pulsing Heart CSS animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I`m working on an animated heart only with CSS.

I want it to pulse 2 times, take a small break, and then repeat it again.

What I have now:

```
small ==> big ==> small ==> repeat animation
```

What I'm going for:

```
small ==> big ==> small ==> big ==> small ==> pause ==> repeat animation
```

How can I do it?

My code :

```css
#button{
  width:450px;
  height:450px;
  position:relative;
  top:48px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  }
#heart img{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 7s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 7s ease-in-out;}

 @keyframes heartFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  14% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  28% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  42% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  70% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

#heart img.top { 
  animation-name: heartFadeInOut; 
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-direction: alternate;

}
```

```html
<div id="heart" >
  <img class="bottom" src="https://goo.gl/nN8Haf" width="100px">
  <img class="top" src="https://goo.gl/IIW1KE" width="100px">
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sLgo180p/).

Comment: Is there some reason why you have used jsfiddle instead of a Stack Snippet integrated in the question? As far as I can see the Stack Snippet works fine for your example.

Comment: Heart with Pulse Animation : https://youtu.be/Jq4diUd10Zs

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can incorporate the pause into the animation. Like so:

```
@keyframes heartbeat
{
  0%
  {
    transform: scale( .75 );
  }
  20%
  {
    transform: scale( 1 );
  }
  40%
  {
    transform: scale( .75 );
  }
  60%
  {
    transform: scale( 1 );
  }
  80%
  {
    transform: scale( .75 );
  }
  100%
  {
    transform: scale( .75 );
  }
}
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/t7f97kf4/

```css
@keyframes heartbeat
{
  0%
  {
    transform: scale( .75 );
  }
  20%
  {
    transform: scale( 1 );
  }
  40%
  {
    transform: scale( .75 );
  }
  60%
  {
    transform: scale( 1 );
  }
  80%
  {
    transform: scale( .75 );
  }
  100%
  {
    transform: scale( .75 );
  }
}

div
{
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation: heartbeat 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div>
Heart
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Working example with pure CSS heart shape:
https://jsfiddle.net/qLfg2mrd/

```css
@keyframes heartbeat
{
  0%
  {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  
  20%
  {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  
  40%
  {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  
  60%
  {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  
  100%
  {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
}

#heart
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  animation: heartbeat 1s infinite;
}

#heart:before,
#heart:after
{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

#heart:after
{
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="heart"></div>
```

Comment: @FernandoSouza You can also make css heart without image - https://jsfiddle.net/qLfg2mrd/

Comment: @DavidWilkinson Bookmark this one too :) - https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ :)

Comment: You mean, the ♥ character? That is easy, just do `&hearts;`. No need for all those `transform`s.

Answer (score 40):

> Pulse 2 times, take a small break, and then repeat it again

Try this. Going with animation `opacity` is a bad choice. `transform: scale()` will do the job.

```css
.heart:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'icons';
  font-size: 21px;
  text-indent: 0;
  font-variant: normal;
  line-height: 21px;
}
.heart {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: inherit;
  margin: 50px auto;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-animation: animateHeart 2.5s infinite;
  animation: animateHeart 2.5s infinite;
}
.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 120px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateZ(0);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.heart:after {
  left: 26%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateZ(0);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animateHeart {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  5% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  15% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
@keyframes animateHeart {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  5% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  15% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
span {
  font-family: 'Cantora One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 165px;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart">
</div>
```

Comment: I need to use images instead of pure CSS, in the final project. But, Thanks! I may use the timing of your animation, which is perfect!

Comment: make no difference. you can scale image also in this way.  Just give a try :)

Comment: Can I alternate images or change background image in this way?

Comment: @FernandoSouza yup. Give a try. I will help you if you encounter any problem.

Comment: I am trying, but first changing some structure as there is text on the heart, and it must stay in the same size.

Comment: How can I change the heart`s size? 190x 210

Comment: I also need to center this animation, can you help me?

Comment: to center this, you have the adjust the "left".  also by setting the width and height with respect to the "left" position, you can manipulate the size of heart. I will update the fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100578/discussion-between-jinu-kurian-and-fernando-souza).

Comment: Never scale things up or they will loose resolution. Maximum possible size should be 1 and other sizes should be below 1 i.e. 0.6

Answer (score 24):

I like [ketan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213296/ketan)'s answer, but I wanted to improve the heart animation to make it more realistic.

- A heart does not double in size when it beats.   10% change in size looks better to me.
- I like it getting both larger *and smaller*
- When it stops moving altogether it looks dead to me.   Even when it isn't beating, it needs to expand or contract a little
- I removed the "alternate directions" code so that it runs the same way through every time
- I explicitly have the heart start end and at normal scale (1) and have the animation in the middle of the sequence.   It seems clearer that way to me.

```css
#heart img{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
 }

 @keyframes heartFadeInOut {
  0% {transform: scale(1);}
  25% {transform: scale(.97);}
  35% {transform: scale(.9);}
  45% {transform: scale(1.1);}
  55% {transform: scale(.9);}
  65% {transform: scale(1.1);}
  75% {transform: scale(1.03);}
  100% {transform: scale(1);}
}

#heart img.bottom { 
  animation-name: heartFadeInOut; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="heart" >
  <img class="bottom" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBCpb.png" width="100px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on various comments and making use of the ♥ we'll get this:

```css
body {
  font-size: 40pt;
  color: red;
}
@keyframes heartbeat {
  0% {
    font-size: .75em;
  }
  20% {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  40% {
    font-size: .75em;
  }
  60% {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  80% {
    font-size: .75em;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: .75em;
  }
}
div {
  animation: heartbeat 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div>
  &hearts;
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #1f1f1f;
}

body:before
{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

.center
{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #1f1f1f;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  padding: 100px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow:20px 20px 45px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.heart
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:#ff0036;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10px,10px);
  animation: ani 1s linear infinite;
}
.heart:before
{
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff0036;
  position: absolute;
  top:-50%;
  left:0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.heart:after
{
  content:'';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff0036;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.center:before
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

@keyframes ani{
  0%{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10px,10px) scale(1);
  }
  25%{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10px,10px) scale(1);
  }
  30%{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10px,10px) scale(1.4);
  }
  50%{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10px,10px) scale(1.2);
  }
  70%{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10px,10px) scale(1.4);
  }
  90%{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10px,10px) scale(1);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10px,10px) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HeartBeat Animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="heart">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5WUV.gif)

for more: [Heart Beating Animation](https://www.codesnail.com/2019/02/heart-beating-animation-using-css.html)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want for your image animation. There is no need of top image. Just use bottom.

```css
#button{
  width:450px;
  height:450px;
  position:relative;
  top:48px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  }
#heart img{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
 }

 @keyframes heartFadeInOut {
  0%
  {    transform: scale( .5 );  }
  20%
  {    transform: scale( 1 );  }
  40%
  {    transform: scale( .5 );  }
  60%
  {    transform: scale( 1 );  }
  80%
  {    transform: scale( .5 );  }
  100%
  {    transform: scale( .5 );  }
}

#heart img.bottom { 
  animation-name: heartFadeInOut; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-direction: alternate;

}
```

```html
<div id="heart" >
  <img class="bottom" src="https://goo.gl/nN8Haf" width="100px">
</div>
```

Comment: Your heart has a mild arrhythmia on Chrome?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr So it's not just me. Why chrome? Why?

Comment: I'm not sure, it could be a Cardiac Symphysis Sinus, but you'd want to check with a CSS expert for a better diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

I needed this for a project I was working on. I was trying to make it look as realistic as possible, and this is what I came up with.

```
@keyframes heartbeat {
    0% {
        transform: scale( .95 );
    }

    20% {
        transform: scale( .97 );
    }

    30% {
        transform: scale( .95 );
    }

    40% {
        transform: scale( 1 );
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale( .95 );
    }
}
```

`animation: heartbeat 1s infinite;`