# How to do CSS keyframe animations in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-web

How can I recreate this [pulsing heart CSS effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762127/3310334) in react-native-web?

```css
@keyframes heartbeat
{
  0%
  {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  
  20%
  {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  
  40%
  {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  
  60%
  {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  
  100%
  {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
}

#heart
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  animation: heartbeat 1s infinite;
}

#heart:before,
#heart:after
{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

#heart:after
{
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="heart"></div>
```

I found [the Animated API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations) but can't see anything about keyframes

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-reanimated: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/next/api/LayoutAnimations/keyframeAnimations/ using this library you can do keyframe animation see the link for more details.